# Git branches management and testing

Tags: git, branch

There is something that I don't really understand in the git branch management system that seems to be the norm describe [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) or the simplest version [here](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

How can we be sure that the code that is being test (by people on a test environment) is actually the same as the code that we deliver?

My understanding is the following:

I've got an eternal master branch that reflect the code in production.

At any given time I can create a Hotfix branch (`Hotfix_A`) to fix a bug. On this branch I will do one or multiple commit to fix the problem and then I will compile this branch to create a deliverable (`deliverable_A`) that will be test by clients. I can't merge these modifications into `master` at this point because the code is not in production.
Then there is a situation where, during this period of time, when the client realize tests to certify that I can deliver this change in production, another hotfix (`Hotfix_B`) is deliver in production (following the same process but quicker).

I'm in a situation where my deliverable_A has been tested and certified but the `master` branch has evolved since. I can't deliver deliverable_A because it doesn't contains the code modification that Hotfix_B has and is already in production.

I can merge the modifications and create a deliverable_C containing both modifications. The problem is nobody will test this version before going into production. Even if I find someone that is up to test this delivrable_C, another hotfix can be done during that time and I've just postpone the problem.

Can someone explain to me what is wrong in my understanding of the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you have a *necessarily* wrong understanding, as you bring up a valid issue - how to handle multiple hotfix branches?

In the scenario you give, where `hotfix-A` is delayed and `hotfix-B` gets applied before A, then there are a couple of assumptions you've made. You have to answer the questions - does `hotfix-B` depend on `hotfix-A` and are the different hotfix branches tested by different clients?

It looks like, if `hotfix-B` passed quicker than `hotfix-A`, then these fixes are not (necessarily or always, be careful here) related. **If** they are related, then maybe you have to impose a rule where you have to **strictly** merge `hotfix-A` **first** before `hotfix-B`. If these two fixes are not related, then you **don't have to** provide a test-case where both A *and* B have been tested together (the reason is because they are not related and fix different problems and it's not expected to have any clashes between each other). That's why we call it a hotfix, since we are rushing things (to this point, see strategy #1 as it addresses this issue).

Also, keep in mind that different companies employ different strategies to managing multiple hotfixes. Strategies like:

1. For instance, after each hotfix, the service version of the application is bumped and all hotfix branches are `rebased` on the latest service version. By rebasing your hotfix branches, you automatically incorporate the previous hotfixes into the current ones. Do this for each hotfix. (Note: in this case, your testers might need to re-test the software... not the best case but what can you do).
2. Each hotfix branch gets merged into master separately, as each hotfix branch works on a separate issue, unrelated to the others. Hotfixes, related to each other, work on the same hotfix branch, i.e. `hotfx-A` is the main hotfix, from it we can branch-off `hotfix-A1`, `hotfix-A2` and `hotfix-A3`. We merge these into `hotfix-A` and then we are ready to merge into master.
3. Each hotfix is based on a main hotfix branch and then everything gets dumped into master.

There are pros and cons to all these methods. Pick one and see if it works for you. Tweak it to your liking and workflow.